# File Picker window not open in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

on Button click file picker window not open in xamarin forms-
I am using Xam.Plugin.FilePicker 
Here is my button event code-

```
async void FilePickerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FileData filedata = new FileData();
                filedata = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
                byte[] data = filedata.DataArray;
                string name = filedata.FileName;
                foreach(byte b in filedata.DataArray)
                {
                    string attachment = b.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe an exception is thrown? Did you try to debug your code? 'windows not open' is unclear behaviour, please elaborate.

Comment: i debug my code but file name showing null value,after click on the button its not opening the file picker window.How to solve this?

Comment: Depends on the OS you might need to add permissions. Follow the important section on https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

Comment: after adding this line it solved my problem => var crossFileData = CrossFilePicker.Current;

Comment: You can edit you question and add the solution, so this thread will be useful for the rest of the community.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this plugin on Android device and it works well. I installed the plugin in all projects and then added these permissions to AndroidManifest.xml file as it is in the documentation.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Then in my MainPage.xaml I created a button

```
<Button Text="Open File" Clicked="Button_Clicked" />
```

And in my MainPage.xaml.cs created event

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
}
```

I picked the file and retrieve the property FileName and DataArray without any problem.

There is a thread on [xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/67832/implementing-file-picker-example-into-a-cross-platform-application) or there is a [issue list](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/issues) on their github.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer forked github project that received quite some fixes, e.g. for Android picking from download folder, OneDrive or Google Drive storage. The project is here:
https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows
(note: I'm one of the contributors).

You just have to change the NuGet package name to Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker, the API is the same.